# Problems with understanding a linked list implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

*Update: Thanks a lot to everybody who responded!!! It made me feel that I'm not completely alone in my efforts to learn Java. Please excuse me, but I guess I didn't clarify enough what I don't get about linked lists and the exercise application  -*

*first - how can a class definition contain an object of itself, OK I know that this is recursion but it's still a very strange and alien concept to me.*

*second - how exactly can a linked list object "link" to another node?*

*third - if two objects are separated by an equals sign it means what - that the second object disappears and what's left of it is it's "name" that now points to the first object or vice versa?*

*then - the thing that I don't get about the program I quoted below is the following: after the linkList class is instantiated it's constructor is called and it gives the object of class Link private Link first the value of null, i.e. sets it pointing to nothing. Then, when the first new node is created the method public void insertFirst is called, it gives the object values to its variables and then something absurd happens - the object first that points to nothing is assigned to the new item thus making both objects pointing to nothing and with the  first = newLink; I'm completely lost...*

I'm doing a college course on Algorithms and Data structures and since the professor is really mean and his explanations are useless I'm trying to learn on my own from a book called Algorithms and data structures by Robert Lafore.

Now I'm learning Linked lists and there is the following code example for a linked list implementation in the book:

Link.java:

```
class Link
   {
   public int iData;              // data item
   public double dData;           // data item
   public Link next;              // next link in list

   public Link(int id, double dd) { // constructor
      iData = id;                 // initialize data
      dData = dd;                 // ('next' is automatically
      }                           //  set to null)

   public void displayLink() {     // display ourself
      System.out.print("{" + iData + ", " + dData + "} ");
      }
   }
```

LinkList.java:

```
class LinkList {
   private Link first;            // ref to first link on list

   public LinkList() {             // constructor
      first = null;               // no links on list yet
      }

   public boolean isEmpty() {      // true if list is empty
      return (first==null);
      }
                                  // insert at start of list
   public void insertFirst(int id, double dd) { // make new link
      Link newLink = new Link(id, dd);
      newLink.next = first;       // newLink --> old first
      first = newLink;            // first --> newLink
      }

   public Link deleteFirst() {     // delete first item
      // (assumes list not empty)
      Link temp = first;          // save reference to link
      first = first.next;         // delete it: first-->old next
      return temp;                // return deleted link
      }

   public void displayList() {
      System.out.print("List (first-->last): ");
      Link current = first;       // start at beginning of list
      while(current != null)      // until end of list,
         {
         current.displayLink();   // print data
         current = current.next;  // move to next link
         }
      System.out.println("");
      }
   }
```

LinkListApp.java:

```
class LinkListApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LinkList theList = new LinkList();  // make new list

      theList.insertFirst(22, 2.99);      // insert four items
      theList.insertFirst(44, 4.99);
      theList.insertFirst(66, 6.99);
      theList.insertFirst(88, 8.99);

      theList.displayList();              // display list

      while( !theList.isEmpty() ) {        // until it's empty,
         Link aLink = theList.deleteFirst();   // delete link
         System.out.print("Deleted ");         // display it
         aLink.displayLink();
         System.out.println("");
         }
      theList.displayList();              // display list
      }
   }
```

I just CANNOT understand the code that inserts and displays items in the linked list class.

How can it be that `newLink.next = first;    and   first = newLink;` after the new object is created?

Please help!

Comment: It's an insert as first item function. :-/

Comment: I do not quite get your problem. Can you describe what exactly you do not understand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each `Link` holds a reference `.next` to the next `Link` element (except the last element, having `.next = null`.

A `LinkList` holds a reference (`.first`) to the first `Link` object it contains.

In order to insert a new `Link` at the front of the `LinkList`, we need to do the following:

1. Create a new `Link` object to insert in front (`newLink`).
2. Let the newly created `Link` point to the previous first `Link` object as its `.next`
3. Reset the `.first` reference of the `LinkList` to the `newLink`object, effectively overwriting the previous reference (marked with a cross below).

[image: Source: See cacoo.com/diagrams/SRZoHdJ4GEn5PKAF]

This is exacly what's going on:

```
public void insertFirst(int id, double dd) {
    Link newLink = new Link(id, dd);
    newLink.next = first;
    first = newLink;
}
```

Comment: Wowo, this diagram is much better than mine. +1 for that.

Comment: @Grigor Petrov You're very welcome. Good luck with the course :)

Answer (score 2):

What may have confused you is that this list implementation is LIFO (Last In First Out), so the last element inserted is the first one returned when traversing.

`newLink.next = first;` puts the former first element as the new element's next (so second)

`first = newLink;` puts the new element at the top of the list

There are many possible ways for linked lists to behave differently, it depends on what kind of collection you want them to be (a queue, a stack) or different patterns (single or double linked, circular) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Assume we have a linked list like this:

```
 first                -> Link("monday")
 Link("monday").next  -> Link("tuesday")
 Link("tuesday").next -> Link("wednesday")
```

Now we want to have the week starting with "sunday".

First we create a new link for "sunday":

```
 Link("sunday")                             # newLink = new Link(id,dd)
```

and tell it, that it's follower is "monday"

```
 first                -> Link("monday")
 Link("sunday").next  -> Link("monday")     # newLink.next = first
 Link("monday").next  -> Link("tuesday")
 Link("tuesday").next -> Link("wednesday")
```

Finally we correct the start of the week

```
 first                -> Link("sunday")     # first = newLink
 Link("sunday").next  -> Link("monday")     
 Link("monday").next  -> Link("tuesday")
 Link("tuesday").next -> Link("wednesday")
```

Answer (score 1):

You add the new `Link` to the head of the `LinkList` object by setting `head = newLink;`

You append the existing list to the new element's `next` by setting `newLink.next = first;`

Answer (score 1):

As your new node is being added, it is being added to the start of the LinkedList, so since the pointer First was pointing to the first node in the List, but on the arrival of a newNode to the same list, this Pointer first must point to the newly added node, and the newly added node must point to the previously established first node, so that it can become the first node of the Linked List.

Hopefully this diagram can explain a bit further :

[image: LINKED LIST IMAGE]

That's why you have to write `newLink.next = first; and first = newLink;`

Comment: @GrigorPetrov : Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)